# How to convert a list of strings representing tuples to tuples of integers?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to convert

```
list_int=['(2,3)','(3,4)']
```

to integer coordinate points:

```
[(2, 3), (4, 8)]
```

I tried this code

```
list_int=['(2,3)','(3,4)']
for x in list_int:
    con= int(x0 for x in list_int)
    print con
```

and I am getting this error

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'

I am new to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove the start and end parenthesis, split each string, and then convert each element to an `int`:

```
result = [[int(x) for x in s[1:-1].split(",")] for s in list_int]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

list_int=['(2,3)','(3,4)'] 

converted = [literal_eval(tup) for tup in list_int]

# [(2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

From the doc of `ast.literal_eval`:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.